# Operators for cv::UMat

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I noticed that there are some code incompatibilities between cv::Mat and cv::UMat -- right now I'm stuck with some missing operators. I found functions for element-wise operations with other matrices, but what is the best way to e.g. just scale the values of a UMat by a float/double or to add a fixed value to all elements?

Comment: JFYI, this [crosspost at OpenCV Answers](http://answers.opencv.org/question/134036/operators-for-cvumat/) already has an explanation.

Comment: I know, but the proposed methods seems to be buggy (see comments). I'm still not sure what the best method is...